# Deletion from vector took less time than deletion from list. Why?

Tags: c++, list, vector

In C++ manual I found next:

> Vectors are relatively efficient adding or removing elements from its
>   end. For operations that involve inserting or removing elements at
>   positions other than the end, they perform worse than the others, and
>   have less consistent iterators and references than lists and
>   forward_lists.

Also, in 'complexity' of 'erase' method of vector I found next:

> Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions) plus the number
>   of elements after the last element deleted (moving).

In 'complexity' of 'erase' method of list next:

> Linear in the number of elements erased (destructions).

But when I tested it in the 30 millions elements in each container (I deleted from 24357 element to 2746591 element), I got that deleting from vector took 5 ms, but from list 8857 ms. Difference is huge and confusing...

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const long int x = 30000000;
    vector<char> v;
    vector<char>::iterator itv1, itv2;
    list<char> l;
    list<char>::iterator itl1, itl2;
    unsigned start, end;

    long int first, last;

    cout << "Please enter first position: \n";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Please enter last position: \n";
    cin >> last;

    for (long int i = 0; i < x; ++i)    {
        char c;
        c = (rand() % 26) + 'a';
        v.push_back(c);
        l.push_back(c);
    }

    cout << "Starting deletion\n";
    start = clock();
    itv1 = v.begin() + first;
    itv2 = v.begin() + last;
    v.erase(itv1, itv2);
    end = clock();
    cout << "End " << end-start << "\n";

    start = clock();
    itl1 = itl2 = l.begin();
    advance(itl1, first);
    advance(itl2, last);
    l.erase(itl1, itl2);
    end = clock();
    cout << "End " << end-start << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain - what causes such difference? My opinion - moving iterators in list much slower than in vectors - but I don't sure.

Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could post code that compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erasing a range of elements from a vector requires merely the move of all trailing elements forward, to the start of the gap. This can be done with a memory move instruction, which is *very* efficient. It depends on the number of trailing elements and not on the number of deleted elements.

Deleting the same number of elements from a list requires iterating over the deleted range in the list and returning each element to the dynamic memory management which is clearly dependent on the number of elements you delete.

**Later**

Compare a delete of a range of 1000 near the start of the vector with the same operation almost at the end, and then do the same with the list. I predict that the vector will be slower in the first case and (much) faster in the second case.

And here's the result:

```
Please enter first position: 
1
Please enter last position: 
1000
Starting deletion
End 10000
End 0
/tmp$ ./del
Please enter first position: 
29999000         
Please enter last position: 
29999999
Starting deletion
End 0
End 360000
```

:-)

Comment: yeah - I tried to delete less elements (2) from the same range (30 mln) - erasing from vector still 5 ms, but from list 30 ms. If I changing range to 0,3 mln but number of elements still 2, deletion from vector took 0 ms, but from list still 30. So I think you completely right!

Comment: Note also that your data structures are using only the simplest of data types. `char` has no destructor and manages no resources. If you used a more complicated data type which itself managed resources, you'd see the deletion time difference close some.

Comment: @laune which compiler do u use? Because in the first case (deletion from beginning) I get deletion from vector 1 ms, from list 44 ms...

Comment: g++ 4.3.3, and don't tell me it's old, I know.

Comment: oh, I don't care about how old is it:) I am just testing in compiler that in VS2010 and in VS2013 (don't exacty know which version of compiler), but I can't test it on my Ubuntu PC. As I write above, results are differ with yours, so it somewhere strange for me...

Answer (score 6):

In your case, likely because you're not measure the erase time, you're measuring the time taken for two `advance` calls and the `erase` call.

But more generally: because O() complexity only tells you about the algorithmic complexity not the actual time taken. O(1) can have a huge constant time value. Worse, the complexity is theoretical; it does not consider the realities of how hardware works.

In fact because the vector delete accesses memory in a linear fashion it can be efficiently cached and predicted whilst the list delete operates in a random access fashion. This can mean that vector delete is faster in practice than list delete when you have a small vector.

Comment: I would give +1, but I do not agree with the last statement: "This can mean that vector delete is faster in practice than list delete". Vector delete is faster than list delete in some situations, but for other situations list delete will be much faster. Even being more cache friendly, if the OP delete only the first element, list will be faster than vector.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed a bit off that sentence, let me correct.

Comment: +1, good answer. I think a lot of programmers don't understand what time complexity actually is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the task you want to do.

Your task takes advantage of random access and contains only a single `erase()`: this plays to the strengths of vector.

I think a more interesting task would be to iterate the list and the vector one element at a time deleting every other element.

This forces sequential access and multiple calls to `erase()`: this will play to the strength of list.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook answer is that list will be faster, but the textbook isn't always right! I can't prove it, but I suspect it is due to the fact that modern computers have special circuitry that allows them to shift blocks of memory around very fast. So while vector deletion is O(N) in some academic sense, in reality it boils down to (can boil down to) a single hardware operation, which ends up being faster than all the traversal and pointer fiddling you have to do when your remove an element from a list.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting all elements with a single call to erase, that means when you delete from vector you get an O(n), but only once. When you delete from list, you will have to iterate to the position 1 (itl1) and to position 2 (itl2), also if you are the deleting a lot of elements, the erase method will have a lot of elements to erase. In other words, unless you are erasing few elements from the begining of the list, you will also have O(n) for lists. Note that for iterating through elements in a vector is much faster than in a list, which may be the cause of those results.

Try deleting only the first element, and you should see the list being much faster than vector.